# Windows 7 slows down badly after staying for night

Tags: windows-7, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the first steps for diagnosing a slow machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/26862/what-are-the-first-steps-for-diagnosing-a-slow-machine)

I don't switch off the computer at work when I go home.

I run Firefox, some IDE's and Skype. These programs are most memory consumable and have many threads running inside.

When I come back to work in the mornings, log in - my computer responds soooo slowly. It tries very hard to restore minimized windows, switch tabs an so on.

I have notices hard drive indicator flashing constantly during that period.

In Resource Monitor I can observe read and write to pagefile.sys at 1Mb\s by the system.
I have tried to switch off swap file, but still, having 4Gb RAM (on 32-bit machine though), it soon crashes my system due to lack of memory.

While, having the computer going hibernate doesn't cause that performance drop.

Is there a way to do have Windows running on relevant speed and having it switched on?

Comment: Some of your program, probably Firefox, have memory leaks and start to too much memory when they're left open. Trying upgrading them or close them more often.

Comment: **My recommendation:** Turn of your computer when you leave work. I find that leaving my PC on causes it to work a lot harder than it needs to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the first steps for diagnosing a slow machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/26862/what-are-the-first-steps-for-diagnosing-a-slow-machine) and/or [How to diagnose slow booting or logon in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/250267/how-to-diagnose-slow-booting-or-logon-in-windows-7) and perhaps also check out [Windows 7 starts getting sluggish over a few days](http://superuser.com/questions/151429/windows-7-starts-getting-sluggish-over-a-few-days) for some ideas.